# fully non-commutative ring with unique factorization decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let me explain, I do a protocol of cryptography that integers work but integers are commutative and I dont want this property. My question is Does there exist a "fully" non-commutative ring with unique factorization decomposition (except multiples of units)?

EDIT:
Fully means:
$ab \neq ba $  when $a\neq b $ and $a,b \in R^*$ which are not units.

I dont need a answer, I mean a explicit ring, work a book of sources to read. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "UFD" stands for "unique factorization domain". Please don't repurpose it for something else.

Comment: You cannot have $ab\neq ba$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $R$ because $aa$ cannot be different from itself. Even if you require $a\neq b$, the condition cannot be met since you always have $0a=a0$ for all $a$ (unless you happen to have the zero ring). Even if you restrict to nonzero distinct $a$ and $b$ you also have to exclude units, since by definition a unit $u$ has a two-sided inverse, so $uv=vu$; and of course $1a=a1$ for all $a\in R$. And presumably you want your ring not be a noncommutative division ring, as that one has unique factorization of nonunits trivially.

Comment: well yes, with your condition. and if maybe I don't have to call it Domain

Comment: If you need to fix the post, then fix it. I stated a bunch of things, so there isn't a "my condition". Right now, what you ask for cannot be done.

Comment: If the ring has no zero divisors and has any non-unit, then it is impossible for any two nonzero nonunits to not commute. For if $a\in R$ is not zero and not a unit, then $aa=a$ would imply $0 = aa-a = a(a-1)$, which would mean that either $a=0$ or $a=1$, which we have excluded. But then $aa\neq a$, neither is zero, neither is a unit,  and yet $(aa)a = a(aa)$.

Comment: `I dont need a answer, I mean a explicit ring, work a book of sources to read.` This is hard to parse. Any sort of post here necessitates "an answer."  You mean you want an example of such a ring **or** (instead of "work"?) a publication on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

As Arturo mentions in the comments, the "fully noncommutative" condition you're asking for cannot be met. But there is a somewhat well-known article that you'd be interested in:

> Cohn, Paul M. "Noncommutative unique factorization domains." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 109.2 (1963): 313-331.

You would probably want to play with the examples given there.